# What does a field of fractions has to do with localization and also integrallity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, fractions

We have discovered today the notion of a field of fractions $(R\setminus \{0\})^{-1}R$ where $R$ is a ring. Somehow I we did not discussed much how this is used in localizations or even more with respect to integral elements/integral closure ect. of a ring. Somehow in the statements about integral elements or integral closure they never speak about a field of fractions even though they use it in each proof.

Since this is new for me I would like to see why they use it in all the proofs, so I want to understand it by heart. Could someone help me mabye?

I would be very thankful.

Comment: You only get a field of fraction when $R$ is an integral domain (doesn't work for all rings). When that is the case then every localization of $R$ takes place inside the field of fractions.

Comment: Integral closure is a bit more subtle. Many known integral domains are integrally closed in their field fractions. A well known counterexample (from geometry) is the integral domain $R=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$. The element $t=y/x$ (or more precisely its coset) is not an element of $R$, but we do have $t^2=x$, so it is integral over $R$. Another non-integrally closed domain would be $D=\Bbb{Z}[2i]$. The number $i=(2i)/2$ is in the field of fractions, and integral over $D$.

Comment: The question has a somewhat wide scope, so it is difficult to give a good answer and/or point you at a duplicate. We have most likely covered the material on the site already, but there may not be a single good older question. Did you search?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen first of all thank you for your answer. So what I don't see is why exaclty we need $R$ to be an integral domain in order to speak about a field of fractions. So I mean if I remember it correctly then $R$ is an integral domain if for all $x,y$ in $R$ with $xy=0\Rightarrow x=0$ or $y=0$. right? But then I can't see why we need this to define an integral domain. Could you maybe explain this?

Comment: Zero divisors in the denominator tell that something is wrong. What would be $(1/2)(1/3)$ in $(R\setminus\{0\})^{-1}R$, when $R=\Bbb{Z}_6$?

Comment: So $(1/2)(1/3)=(1/6)$ by the rule in a field of fractions. but now since $R=\Bbb{Z}_6$ we have that $6=0~mod~6$ right? But this would not work since $0\not \in R\setminus \{0\}$. Aha and this can happen in $R$ since $R$ is not an integral domain, otherwise this would not happen. Did I get this right?

Comment: If yes could you also explain again your comment that every localization of $R$ takes place inside the field of fractions

Answer (score 0):

The guidelines for the construction of the ring of fractions are those for the field of fractions.

Let $R$ be a (commutative) integral domain (with unit) and consider the (regular) set $S=R - \{0\}$. Let $s_1,s_2 \in S$. Since $R$ is an integral domain, $s_1s_2=0$ gives $s_1=0$ or $s_2=0.$ Thus, $S$ is closed under multiplication. Define an equivalence relation on $R \times S$ by $(r_1,s_1) \sim (r_2,s_2)$ if and only if $s_3(r_1s_2-r_2s_1)=0$ for some $s_3 \in S$. For this particular pair $(R,S)$, the latter condition can simply be stated as $r_1s_2=r_2s_1$. Together with the two operations $(r_1,s_1)+(r_2,s_2)=(r_1s_2+r_2s_1,s_1s_2)$ and $(r_1,s_1) \times (r_2,s_2)=(r_1r_2,s_1s_2)$, you obtain a field $((R,S),+,\times)$ called the field of fractions.

This procedure generalizes to more general commutative rings $R$ and multiplicative sets $S$. You retrieve the former when $R$ is an integral domain and $S=R-P$ where $P=(0)$ is the zero ideal. The ideal $P$ as defined is a prime ideal: If $r_1r_2 \in P$ then $r_1 \in P$ or $r_2 \in P$, as $R$ is an integral domain.

So the localization of a commutative ring $R$ with respect to the multiplicative set $S$ is the set $R \times S / \sim$ under these two operations. It is usually denoted $S^{-1}R$. The ring $S^{-1}R$ is a subring of the field of fractions when $S$ excludes $\{0\}$ and $R$ is an integral domain.

If $P$ is a prime ideal and $R$ a commutative ring, then $S=R-P$ is a multiplicative set, since $s_1s_2 \in P$ implies $s_1 \in P$ or $s_2 \in P$, $s_1,s_2 \in S$. Denoting the non-units in $S^{-1}R$ by $(S^{-1}R)^{*}$, you have the following:

> $(r,s) \in (S^{-1}R)^{*}$ if and only if $r \in P$.

Indeed, if $r \in S$ then $(r,s)\times(s,r)=(1,1)$ and $(r,s) \in S^{-1}R$ is a unit. Conversely, if $(r_1,s_1) \in S^{-1}R$ is a unit, then $(r_1,s_1) \times (r_2,s_2)=(1,1)$ gives $s(r_1r_2-s_1s_2)=0$ some $s \in S$. Hence, $r_1sr_2=ss_1s_2$ and $r_1 \in S$.

As such, we get that $(r_1s_2-r_2s_1,s_1s_2), (r_1r_3,s_1s_3) \in (S^{-1}R)^{*}$ whenever $(r_1,s_1),(r_2,s_2) \in (S^{-1}R)^{*}$ and $(r_3,s_3) \in S^{-1}R$. This means that $(S^{-1}R)^{*}$ form an ideal in $S^{-1}R$ and so is a local ring.